# makefile.in not found while installing systemC

Tags: installation, systemc

I'm trying to install SystemC on mac (x86, macOs 13.0.1). I followed the steps described in the docs:

```
$ cd path/to/systemc-2.3.3
$ mkdir objdir
$ cd objdir
$ export CXX=g++
$ ../configure
```

But when I run the configure, I have an error cause it says that it cannot found `src/makefile.in`. Do you have any idea why this happens or just any hint of where to seek for solutions?
Here's the complete logs, which seems to be normal until the error :

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0
// plenty of checking ...
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
//...
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `src/Makefile.in'
```

[EDIT]: Advancement :
By running `autoconf` and `automake` in source directory, I saw that some stuff were missing, so I runned `aclocal`and `automake --add-missing`. I can now run `automake` in source dir without problems.

Running `../configure` now gives me :

```
$ checking ...
$ ../configure: line 2761: syntax error near unexpected token `1.10'
$ ../configure: line 2761: `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(1.10 tar-pax -Werror -Wno-portability no-define subdir-objects foreign)'
```

Comment: Does building in the source directory work?

Comment: There is no Makefile.in in the src folder, so I can't build anything.

Comment: Makefile.in should be generated from Makefile.am. What happens if you run `automake` (and `autoconf`) in the source directory?

Comment: I managed to run this, check edit in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up removing the `1.10` in the configure.ac and it worked.